# linux ps aux command

Tags: linux, awk, cut

How obtain the running process with absolute path name from ps command

```
13598 ?        Ssl    0:00 /opt/something --run-id 2 -n /home/laks/f1 -l l.log
```

I need the output as -

```
/opt/something --run-id 2 -n /home/laks/f1 -l l.log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, just use `awk`.

```
ps aux | awk '{print $11}'
```

Otherwise just do `man awk` and look at the field separator.

Answer (score 6):

Using user-defined format in `ps`:

`ps xa -o cmd`

Answer (score 2):

Okay I got the answer ,

> cat /proc/13598/cmdline

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
which `ps aux | cut -c 66- | cut -d\  -f 1`
```

will list absolute paths of all of the processes, you could work with that.